# How to delete line break in textmate

Tags: textmate, text-editor

How to find and delete all the line breaks? I tried \n and it doesn't work! Regular expression? what kinda of expression?

Comment: Found out the answer in textmate irb channel: 
option return to search literal line breaks in the find and replace panel, 
\n works in the regex search and won't work in literal search mode.

Comment: Since you found out, answer your own question and then accept it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I found the answer in the [TextMate IRC channel](http://macromates.com/support).

Press `Option Return` to search for literal line breaks in the Find and Replace panel.

Searching for `\n` works if you select the "Regular Expression" option, but won't work in the literal search mode.

Answer (score 8):

Without regex (regular search):

```
Alt + ⏎
```

Answer (score 0):

Select the empty space in between the lines and Copy. Then Select the block of text you want to remove line breaks from. Go to Find & Replace. Paste the copied empty space in the Find field. Type a space in the Replace field. Hold Option, which toggles Replace All to In Selection, then click In Selection. This should do the trick.